# A wierd problem that group_by() doesn't work?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with 3 factor columns and 4 numeric columns. I want to use group_by() to summarize it. But no matter how I try it doesn't work, there is no group.

```
freetick <- read.csv("FreeTickAll.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(dplyr)
group1 <- freetick %>% group_by(Habitat, Month) %>% summarize(
meanAd = mean(Adult),
meanNy = mean(Nymph), 
meanLa = mean(Larva)
)
group1
```

The result:

```
> group1
    meanAd   meanNy  meanLa
1  0.6129032  4.258065  20.1129
```

And my group1 data.frame also show:

```
     mean Ad   mean Ny  mean La
1   0.6129032   4.258065   20.1129
```

Comment: If it doesns't work, it may be better to show a small reproducible example using `dput` for others to test

Comment: Thanks! it works! Is it because "library(dplyr)" doesn't successful or others? I'm a newbie.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ""library(dplyr)" doesn't successful or others". This seems like it's not reproducible: if specifying package names (i.e. adding `dplyr::`) in front of functions helps, you probably have functions in loaded packages that conflict with each other. You might solve that by just restarting R, but that isn't a situation that other people will be able to reproduce

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If a function is common in multiple packages and those packages are loaded into the working env, then there is a possibility of masking the function from the last loaded package.  In such cases, either restart the R session with only the package of interest loaded (`dplyr` in this case) or specify the function to be loaded explicitly from the package of interest (`dplyr::summarise`)

```
freetick %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Habitat, Month) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(meanAd = mean(Adult),
                     meanNy = mean(Nymph), 
                     meanLa = mean(Larva))
```